# Uploading Image via Magento 1 SOAP API throws errors in 1.9.3 release

Tags: magento-1.9, soap-api-v2

We are using **SOAP API** to upload the image files to our Magento server.

These image files are stored in our **backend ERP system**. Is this know issue of Magento 1.9.3.1?

Error is `Cannot Create Image`.

Comment: Could you please add the code that does the image upload to your post ?

Comment: It worked after resetting all permission for folders.